# Access to the computer information from Electron

Tags: electron

I'm creating a small project with Electron and I need to access to some computer session information:

- The current user full name
- The current connected wifi

Is this possible? I've read the documentation but I don't see any reference to this.

Thanks

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron doesn't provide that information, you will need to use the relevant platform specific APIs to obtain it. Fortunately it seems like people have already published some NPM packages to get that info, for example the username could be obtained using [fullname](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fullname) and the WiFi name could be obtained using [wifi-name](https://github.com/kevva/wifi-name).